# Windows 11 update broke network access for nodejs and other apps

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

After updating to Windows 11 22H2, some of my apps aren't able to connect to internet.

First I noticed that all `npm` commands would fail with `ECONNRESET` when trying to reach `registry.npmjs.org`. Running npm from a VM or WSL works fine but fails to connect when running from GitBash or Windows CMD/Powershell.

Then I noticed that certain apps like Battle.net, Steam and GeForce Experience are also not able to reach internet. But accessing web from browsers like Chrome/Egde/Firefox works fine.

Pinging/Tracerouting the above services from CMD works fine, including NPM registry.

Then I've updated my Docker for Desktop to latest version, and everything magically started working. Then after restarting my machine, things are broken again with the same identical symptoms.

Things already tried/checked:

- No proxy is configured for npm or OS in general
- Same symptoms with/without VPN
- switching npm registry http/https
- reinstalling `Nodejs` and `npm` (latest version)
- clearing npm cache and resetting `.npmrc`
- Reinstalling WSL-2/Docker
- Enabling/Disabling Hyper-V
- Flushing/Changing DNS
- Disabling Anti-virus
- Restarting/Reinstalling network adapter drivers
- Swapping network router. Connecting to phone's hotspot

Comment: What exact commands fail from GitBash or Windows `cmd`/`powershell`?

Comment: `npm install`, `npm login` etc. all result in `ECONNRESET`

Comment: Possible issue with Windows Firewall?

Comment: My firewall is managed by Kaspersky. And i've tried disabling it and reinstalling it.

Comment: I have Windows 11 22H2 running fine here. In your case, roll back to the prior version. Windows.old should still be there.  See then if you can see what is breaking.

Comment: actually ended up re-installing the OS, so far things are working.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up re-installing Windows, so the issue was likely unrelated (at least directly) to 11 22H2 update

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I have found Kaspersky to be the culprit (especially if you are part of the Windows Insider Program and getting preview builds).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).